# How to run both Python scripts since the startup, launched from bash script on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, concurrent-processing

A pair of my Python scripts are,
`pyserial.py`
`predict.py`

My `bash.sh` looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh 
python3 path/pyserial.py & 
python3 path/predict.py &
```

To run the bash on startup I edited `crontab` as,
`@reboot sh path/bash.sh &`

But on startup, only `pyserial.py` runs. Surprisingly, if I run the bash script using terminal as,
`sh path/bash.sh`
then both run. But on startup only the `pyserial.py` runs. What can I do ?

Comment: Why not run both scripts directly from cron without the bash wrapper script?

Comment: Shall I put @reboot python3 path/code.py & in Crontab ?

Comment: Remove `&` from the last line, or just run both of them as cron jobs.

Comment: First of all, you should put the proper shebang in your python script: `#!/usr/bin/env python` Then make it executable. After that you can run the script at reboot by adding `@reboot /path/to/your/script.py` in your crontab.

Comment: I did these all. Now I think there might be a problem with my pyserial.py. because now i am trying with 3 files. 2 runs simultaneously but pyserial.py does not start. Although pyserial.py runs on its own just fine !

Comment: The file is executable. When I execute it 3 files starts running. But at startup only 2 starts running.

Comment: You can always add `>> /some/log/file.txt` to the end of your cron statement to write to a logfile.

Comment: @FarhanAvro Try to add `sleep 20` before the cronjob:  `@reboot  sleep 20 && sh path/bash.sh &`. pyserial.py might be not working because it (as its name says) connects to a serial port which might not yet be ready when the script starts immediately at boot up.